# Identify this (supposedly Ultra ATA) hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ibook

This ia a hard drive I pulled off my cousin's bricked iBook G4 ([specs](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp43)). The specs say the interface is Ultra ATA, which my research suggests is simply IDE, but it doesn't look like any IDE connector I've seen.

Here's the connector:

[image: connector]

Notice how there's only 1 row of pins, unlike 2 in IDE.

Here's the label:

[image: label]

Here's the spot in the mobo that it came from:

[image: mobo]

A link to the appropriate SATA/USB adapter (preferably under $5) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're going to downvote, explain why. I have followed all the guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you ripped it out with some of the laptop parts. :)
It looks like that connectors is supposed to be removable..

Comment: yes! it's IDE underneath :)

Answer (score 2):

This looks a lot like the weird adaptors that Dell used to do - with a little bit of persuasion you should be able to pull the adaptor on the drive off of the drive to reveal the usual pin-outs.

You would probably notice a seam between the adaptor you're seeing and the 'usual' connector on the PCB.

This shouldn't need much force, and apparently you may need to rock a little to get it loose according to this [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dk2-YU6GR5A&feature=player_detailpage#t=176s) video. You can then attach this adaptor to a replacement drive or use a standard USB -> IDE adaptor to the drive itself.